# Proving that $K$ is the smallest value so that the inequality holds

Tags: calculus, inequality

I was asked to show that $|a+b|^p\leq 2^p\left(|a|^p+|b|^p\right)$, which is somewhat trivial,
$$|a+b|^p\leq\left(|a|+|b|\right)^p\leq2^p\max(|a|^p,|b|^p)\leq2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p),$$
however, it was suggested to me that $2^{p-1}$ is the smallest value such that the inequality holds (i.e. $|a+b|^p\leq K\left(|a|^p+|b|^p\right)$ with $K\geq2^{p-1}$. How would one show this?

Comment: If $p=1$, the triangle inequality implies $K=1<2^1$.

Comment: If you fix $p$ first, then $K=2^p$ is not the smallest, $2^{p-1}$ is. On the other hand, the smallest exponent base that works for all $p$ is $2$. So you have to be a bit clearer in your question.

Comment: I made a mistake while writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best constant would be $2^{p-1}$. Actually one has by Jensen's inequality that
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{1}{2}u+\dfrac{1}{2}v\right)^{p}\leq\dfrac{1}{2}(u^{p}+v^{p})
\end{align*}
for $u,v\geq 0$.

To see that it is the best, consider the $u=v$

For suppose some $K>0$ is such that $K<2^{p-1}$ and $(u+v)^{p}\leq K(u^{p}+v^{p})$, then with $u=v$, $v>0$ we have $2^{p}v^{p}\leq K 2v^{p}$ and hence $K\geq 2^{p-1}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you expand more on the linear dependence part?

Comment: Sorry, it is not linear dependence but equality.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{p}$ is not the smallest constant. In fact $|a+b|^{p} \leq 2^{p-1} (|a|^{p}+|b|^{p})$ for $p>$1. This follows from convexity of the function $x \to x^{p}$.